# Binding 'this' and getting this

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('.btn-delete').on('click', this.confirm.bind(this));
```

Above, on click it runs:

```
p.confirm  = function(e) {

    if(!$(this).hasClass('danger')){

        $(this).addClass('danger');

        $(this).bind('mouseleave',function(){    
            $(this).removeClass('danger');
            $(this).unbind('mouseleave');
        });
    }
    else{   
        this.delete();
    }
};
```

I'm having trouble with this. I need this to get the button but I also need this to access another method (this.delete). I've tried bind but it faisl to work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try using [proxy](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) and [event.currentTarget](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_currenttarget.asp)

Comment: Perhaps you explain what you want to HAPPEN instead of trying to fix code you decided was what you needed. Perhaps there is an easier way?

Comment: I have no idea which `this` need to refer to what, if you explain that, I am sure this is just a matter of caching `this` somewhere

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I'm understanding your question correctly, you want to be able to pass the clicked element as `this` to the `p.confirm` function. You should be able to do this by using `call`, or by using `p.confirm` as the handler:

```js
// using call
$('.btn-delete').on('click', function (e) {
    p.confirm.call(this, e);
});

// as handler
$('.btn-delete').on('click', p.confirm);
```

Assuming that `this.delete` is actually `p.delete`, just use `call` in the handler to pass the clicked element as `this` to the `delete` method:

```js
p.confirm = function (e) {
    var self = $(this); // cache lookup, "this" is the clicked element
    if (!self.hasClass('danger')) {
        self.addClass('danger');
        self.bind('mouseleave', function () {
            self.removeClass('danger');
            self.unbind('mouseleave');
        });
    } else {
        p.delete.call(this); // pass clicked element to use as "this" in p.delete
    }
};
```